# How do I have the nearest element to a certain element in a set?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, set

Let say that I have a set as so:

```
Set<DueDate> dueDates;

class DueDate{
     Date date;
}
```

I need to find the nearest date element that comes right after a specified date.

The set contains around a 1000 entries. Is it ok if I just iterate over the set to find the nearest date entry or I have to use some type of sort or data structure to do it in a more efficient way.

Comment: Use a `TreeSet`.  It has a whole bunch of extra methods for doing this kind of thing.  In this case, you probably want the `ceiling` method.

Comment: Don't use `Date`. Use `Instant` or `LocalDate`, whichever matches your data.

Comment: Is this operation something you need to do often compared to other operations on the set like add, remove or contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` is a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) implementation. Your requirements are not precise, so I'm not sure if you are looking for the [`higher()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#higher(E)) (strictly greater) or [`ceiling()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling(E)) (greater or equal) method, but one of those should meet your needs.

Comment: I am looking for the higher (the date that comes right after it.)

Comment: @daniel Okay. Does this answer your question or do you need more information.